# set property of Object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, typeerror

I have an `Array` of `Objects` like so:

```
manualInputHeaders = [
    {text: 'Store No', title: 'Enter Destination Store Number'},
    {text: 'Promise Date', title: 'Enter promise ship data', classes: {classAdditions: 'tooltipInput'}}
]
```

I'm trying to set with

```
manualInputHeaders[0].classes.classAdditions = 'setMe'
```

However, chrome console gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'classAdditions' of undefined
```

How can a property of an `Object` within an `Array` be set?

Comment: Try: `manualInputHeaders[1].classes.classAdditions = 'setMe'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the object first (if it doesn't already exist):

```
manualInputHeaders[0].classes = manualInputHeaders[0].classes || {};
manualInputHeaders[0].classes.classAdditions = 'setMe';
```

Answer (score 0):

Element zero doesn't have a classes attribute, which is why classes.classAdditions gives the an undefined error. Create the classes element and all should be well.